# Android: contenidos de fragment sobrepuestos

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas noches soy nuevo en la programación en Android Studio y actualmente estoy desarrollando en Java. Estoy tratando de aprender a usar fragments,para ello hice una app muy básica pero los elementos de cada uno de los fragments se sobreponen unos a otros,dichos fragment los declaro en el activity_main.xml.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ojala me puedan ayudar con esto ,me urge poder hacer que funcione.Saludos.

**main_Activity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TabLayout tab;
    TabItem debate,lista,debatir;
    ViewPager vista;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tab=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabBar);
        debate=(TabItem)findViewById(R.id.generar_debate);
        lista=(TabItem)findViewById(R.id.lista_debate);
        debatir=(TabItem)findViewById(R.id.debatir);
        vista=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.vista);
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter=new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tab.getTabCount());
        vista.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        vista.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tab));
        tab.setupWithViewPager(vista);

        tab.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                vista.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**PageAdapter.Java**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private int numero;
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,int numero){
        super (fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
        this.numero=numero;

    }
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                debate tab1 = new debate();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                listar tab2 = new listar();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                comentar tab3 = new comentar();
                return tab3;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return numero;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en tu archivo xml estas agregando los fragmentos que se sobreponen entre si,
solo remueve los fragmetos.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/comentar"
        android:name="com.example.debate_final.comentar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent "
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

y

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/listar"
        android:name="com.example.debate_final.listar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent "
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: en el emulador no  aparecen los elementos añadidos en cada fragment si  quito los fragment del activity_main.xml ,se ven los fragments vacios :(.